# Two-way binding with range and number input in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm just starting to play around with AngularJS and trying to understand the binding technique. For starters, I tried to make a simple conversion calculator (dozens to pieces, pieces to dozens). That worked well, but when I tried to bind both a **range** input and a **number** input to the same model property the **number** input does not update when the **range** value is adjusted.  I have a jsfiddle showing the behavior:

common javascript for broken and working fiddles:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CalcCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var num = 0.0;
    $scope.qty = new Quantity(12);
    $scope.num = num;
});

function Quantity(numOfPcs) {
    var qty = numOfPcs;
    var dozens = numOfPcs / 12;

    this.__defineGetter__("qty", function () {
        return qty;
    });

    this.__defineSetter__("qty", function (val) {
        qty = val;
        dozens = val / 12;
    });

    this.__defineGetter__("dozens", function () {
        return dozens;
    });

    this.__defineSetter__("dozens", function (val) {
        dozens = val;
        qty = val * 12;
    });
}
```

[BROKEN FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/garethconner/2Pk3M/)

html:

```
<div ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
    <form>
        <label for="pcs">Pieces:</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty.qty" size="20" id="pcs"
        />
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" ng-model="qty.qty" />
        <br/>
        <label for="numOfDozens">Dozens</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty.dozens" size="20"
        id="numOfDozens" />
    </form>
</div>
```

However, binding two **number** inputs to the same model property seems to work fine as shown in this fiddle:

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/garethconner/2Pk3M/1/)

html:

```
<div ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
    <form>
        <label for="pcs">Pieces:</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty.qty" size="20" id="pcs"
        />
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" ng-model="qty.qty" />
        <br/>
        <label for="numOfDozens">Dozens</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty.dozens" size="20"
        id="numOfDozens" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to get a **range** and **number** input bound to a single model property in AngularJS?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think type="range" is supported: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1189  You would likely have to write your own directive for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that the input type="range" works with **Strings** and not with **Numbers** (while input type="number" only works with Numbers).

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/range

> The range state represents a control for setting the element's value to
>   a string representing a number.

If you add `val = parseInt(val)` as your first instruction on the `qty` setter it should work:

```
this.__defineSetter__("qty", function (val) {        
    val = parseInt(val);
    qty = val;
    dozens = val / 12;
});
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/2Pk3M/2/

Comment: Isn't a range input basically a number select? Why are they using strings?

Comment: It should be `parseInt(val, 10);`

Comment: @LiviuT. They probably used a string to be backwards-compatible. On older browsers that don’t implement `type="range"`, the `input` will still be usable as a text field, with a string-type `value`. Making `value` still be a string on newer browsers avoids browser compatibility bugs.

Comment: It should be `Number(val);`

Answer (score 7):

I think this solution is more generic.

```
myApp.directive('input', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if ('type' in attrs && attrs.type.toLowerCase() === 'range') {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(parseFloat);
        }
    }
};
```

});

[full explanation](https://liamnewmarch.co.uk/input-range-angular/)

Comment: I like this solution. Although I replaced `parseFloat` with `Number` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using `ng-model-options`. I changed [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qg55y4m4/6/) and here is the code:

**html**:

```
<div ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
    <form>
        <label for="pcs">Pieces:</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty.qty" size="20" id="pcs" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"/>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" ng-model="qty.qty" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="numOfDozens">Dozens</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="qty.dozens" size="20"
        id="numOfDozens" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**js**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CalcCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var num = 1.0;
    $scope.qty = {
    qty:function (val) {
        return arguments.length ? (num = parseFloat(val)) : num;
     }, 
     dozens: function (val) {
            return arguments.length ? (num = val*12) : num/12;
        }
     };
});
```