# Parsing integers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, math, angularjs, string-parsing

I am using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) in one of our application.

In the code below, while loading the page the expression addition (number, valuetoadd) parses correctly and give output as `1+1=2` but while changing the input it doesn't parse correctly and it gives output as `1+2=12'.

Where do I need to change?

```
<div ng-controller='MathsController'>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="1" ng-model='valuetoadd'/>

    <p>Addition table of <b>{{valuetoadd}}</b></p>

    <div ng-repeat='number in numbers'>
        {{number}} + {{valuetoadd}} = {{ addition(number,valuetoadd) }}
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MathsController($scope) 
    {
        $scope.valuetoadd= 1;
        $scope.numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; 
        $scope.addition = function(number,valuetoadd)
        {
            return number+valuetoadd;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `return number + +multiplier`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>May be `number` beging passed as a string.
Try:</s>

```
        $scope.addition = function(number, multiplier)
        {
            return + number + multiplier;
        }
```

`+` would convert the string into number.

**EDIT:**
Now, I see that `multiplier` is passed as string.
So IT has to be converted instead...

Sorry that I did not read the code carefully.

```
        $scope.addition = function(number, multiplier)
        {
            return number + +multiplier;
        }
```

Thank you @Artur for pointing this out.

Comment: No, its the multiplier being passed as string. This won't fix the problem. But the assumption in general is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the root of the problem lies here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1189

Also read this SO topic: [Two-way binding with range and number input in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116017/two-way-binding-with-range-and-number-input-in-angularjs)

As a workaround you can use the solutions proposed by [thefrontender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640415/thefrontender) and [tosh shimayama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238847/tosh-shimayama).

It's worth noticing, though, that it is the **multiplier** who requires parsing to integer, not the `number`. See my comment to your question.

Comment: Thanks Artur. It was much helpful

Answer (score 3):

Another quick fix is to multiply value by 1 before addition. This will force JavaScript to convert value from string to integer.

Example:

{{value*1 + 10}}

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to coerce the variables into some sort of numeric type (values from HTML inputs are passed as string by default)

```
$scope.addition = function (number, multiplier) {
    return number + parseInt(multiplier, 10);
}
```